# SocketCAN + Express.js + Node.js + Socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io, socketcan

So I've installed the SocketCAN, Express, and Socket.io node modules.

What I want to do, is: 
*initialize a Socket via Socket.io on a Express server
*use socketCAN "node-can" module on the server to send messages to my Frontend (Angular6)

What i've done so far:

*Created a Express server and initialized Socket.io and node-can there
*Being able to connect to my socket in my App

Here is the code achieving this:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const path = require('path');
    const http = require('http');
    const socketIO = require('socket.io');
    var can = require('socketcan');

    var channel = can.createRawChannel("vcan0", true);

    channel.start();

    const app = express();
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/akkaDiagTool')));

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/akkaDiagTool/index.html'));
    });

    const server = http.createServer(app);

    const io = socketIO(server);

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      console.log('socket connected');

     socket.on('can message', (from, msg) => {
        msg.channel.addListener("onMessage", function(data) {console.log(data);});
        console.log('Recieved message by', from , 'sayin ', msg);
      });

  socket.on('disconnected', (socket) => {
    console.log('socket disconnected');
  })
})
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`)
})
```

So when i Start my app and send a can message with socketcan:`cansend vcan0 37F#0000000012343412`
i will only see the log of my `msg.channel.addListener("onMessage", function(data) {console.log(data);});`

but not the `console.log('Recieved message by', from , 'sayin ', msg);` log

my Angular Component looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

@Component({
.
.
.
})
export class StaticDataComponent implements OnInit {
  socket;

  constructor() {
    this.socket = io();
    this.socket.on('can message', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

The Socket should be connected, since i get the `socket connected` log in my console.

Any help would be appreciated

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, I managed to figure it out.

I had to io.emit() inside an socket.emit with socket.io on the server:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  //create canChannel with socketcan(node-can)
  var channel = can.createRawChannel('vcan0', true);

  //emit messagees to the *can message* listening to the canChannel
  socket.emit('can message', channel.addListener('onMessage', (data) => {
    io.emit('can message', data);
  }));

  channel.start();
  //disconnect
  socket.on('disconnected', (socket) => {
    console.log('socket disconnected');
  });
```

and here the code inside the Angular Component:

```
constructor() {
    this.socket = io();
    this.socket.on('can message', (msg) => {
      console.log('data', msg);
    });
  }
```

The provided code is minimalistic and just loggin the data in the developer console.